# Make div not affected by other div's size

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm creating some editable card as follow. When I click on the edit icon on first card, the shadow will show and it makes my div taller.

My problem is, can I make it so that when the shadow effect shows the other divs under it don't move/changes position like that. Also, this code is supposedly put on a snippet. When the shadow shows, it make the preview window (body) grow taller and things under it move downward. I want to make the window stays the same height before and after the shadow shows up.

Any help appreciated.

```js
$(".card").click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 0) {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $(this).val(1);
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).val(0);
  }
});

$(".action").click(function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).parent().parent();
  thisCard.addClass("edit");
  thisCard.css({"width": "238px"});
  thisCard.find(".title").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".action").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".action-edit").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".input-group").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  if (thisCard.find(".input-sub-line").length == 0) {
    thisCard.find(".input-main").val(thisCard.find(".title").text());
  }
  else {
    thisCard.find(".input-main").val(thisCard.find(".title-main").text());
    thisCard.find(".input-sub").val(thisCard.find(".title-sub").text());
  }
  thisCard.find(".input-main").focus();
  thisCard.removeClass("clicked");
});

$(".check").click(function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  thisCard.removeClass("edit");
  thisCard.css({"width": "240px"});
  thisCard.find(".title").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action-edit").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".input-group").css({"display": "none"});
  if (thisCard.find(".input-sub-line").length == 0) {
    thisCard.find(".title").text(thisCard.find(".input-main").val());
  }
  else {
    thisCard.find(".title-main").text(thisCard.find(".input-main").val());
    thisCard.find(".title-sub").text(thisCard.find(".input-sub").val());
  }
  thisCard.removeClass("clicked");
});

$(".cancel").click(function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  thisCard.removeClass("edit");
  thisCard.css({"width": "240px"});
  thisCard.find(".title").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action-edit").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".input-group").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.removeClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: table;
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 32px auto;
}

.card .content {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .content .title,
.card .content .input {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 24px;
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
}

.card .content .input {
  display: none;
}

input {
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  width: 100%;
}

input:focus {
  outline-style:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}

.card .content .action {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 36px;
  padding: 24px 16px;
  text-align: right;
}

.card .content .action-edit {
  display: none;
  width: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

.check,
.cancel {
  height: 34.5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.action-edit > .check i,
.action-edit >.cancel i {
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.cancel i {
  color: #333;
}

.check i {
  color: #00c983; 
}

.check-tall,
.cancel-tall {
  height: 45.5px;
}

.check-tall i,
.cancel-tall i {
  line-height: 46px !important;
}

.cancel {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4; 
}

.card .content .action i {
  font-size: 14px; 
  color: #333;
}

.card .content .action i:hover {
  color: #00c983; 
}

.clicked {
  background-color: #CAF1FF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 0 rgba(0,153,255,0.3);
}

.edit {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #00c983;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 0 rgba(0,153,255,0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 12px; 
}

.subtitle-label {
  color: #999; 
}

.input-sub {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.input-sub-line {
  display: table-row; 
  width: 100%;
}

.input-sub-label {
  display: table-cell; 
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999;
}

.input-sub {
  display: table-cell; 
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group {
  display: none; 
  padding: 22px 24px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" value=0>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">Education</div>
    <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="input-main"></div>
    <div class="action"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></div>
    <div class="action-edit">
      <div class="cancel"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
      <div class="check"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="caption">1-Attribute Card</div>

<div class="card" value=0>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title"><span class="title-main">Education</span><br><span class="subtitle"><span class="subtitle-label">Code </span><span class="title-sub">030</span></span></div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-main">
      <div class="input-sub-line">
        <div class="input-sub-label">Code</div> 
        <input class="input-sub" type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="action"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></div>
    <div class="action-edit">
      <div class="cancel cancel-tall"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
      <div class="check check-tall"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="caption">2-Attributes Card</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Pete also chrome. The card and captions under it moves slightly, like 2 or 3px and it really bothers me

Comment: Ah right, I was clicking the wrong thing :) Looks like you need to make sure your inputs are the same height as your non inputs so when you hide / show, when swapping between the two types, there will be no height difference to cause the jumping effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question correctly, but the only movement I see is caused by the border that gets applied to `.card`. If you add an initial border to the `.card` before you edit it, the element won't increase in size and it won't move. I made the border transparent, so it is not going to be visible.

```js
$(".card").click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 0) {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $(this).val(1);
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).val(0);
  }
});

$(".action").click(function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).parent().parent();
  thisCard.addClass("edit");
  thisCard.css({"width": "238px"});
  thisCard.find(".title").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".action").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".action-edit").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".input-group").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  if (thisCard.find(".input-sub-line").length == 0) {
    thisCard.find(".input-main").val(thisCard.find(".title").text());
  }
  else {
    thisCard.find(".input-main").val(thisCard.find(".title-main").text());
    thisCard.find(".input-sub").val(thisCard.find(".title-sub").text());
  }
  thisCard.find(".input-main").focus();
  thisCard.removeClass("clicked");
});

$(".check").click(function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  thisCard.removeClass("edit");
  thisCard.css({"width": "240px"});
  thisCard.find(".title").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action-edit").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".input-group").css({"display": "none"});
  if (thisCard.find(".input-sub-line").length == 0) {
    thisCard.find(".title").text(thisCard.find(".input-main").val());
  }
  else {
    thisCard.find(".title-main").text(thisCard.find(".input-main").val());
    thisCard.find(".title-sub").text(thisCard.find(".input-sub").val());
  }
  thisCard.removeClass("clicked");
});

$(".cancel").click(function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  thisCard.removeClass("edit");
  thisCard.css({"width": "240px"});
  thisCard.find(".title").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action").css({"display": "table-cell"});
  thisCard.find(".action-edit").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.find(".input-group").css({"display": "none"});
  thisCard.removeClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: table;
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 32px auto;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
}

.card .content {    
display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 86px;
}

.card .content .title,
.card .content .input {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 24px;
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
}

.card .content .input {
  display: none;
}

input {
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  width: 100%;
}

input:focus {
  outline-style:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}

.card .content .action {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 36px;
  padding: 24px 16px;
  text-align: right;
}

.card .content .action-edit {
  display: none;
  width: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

.check,
.cancel {
  height: 34.5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.action-edit > .check i,
.action-edit >.cancel i {
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.cancel i {
  color: #333;
}

.check i {
  color: #00c983; 
}

.check-tall,
.cancel-tall {
  height: 45.5px;
}

.check-tall i,
.cancel-tall i {
  line-height: 46px !important;
}

.cancel {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c4c4c4; 
}

.card .content .action i {
  font-size: 14px; 
  color: #333;
}

.card .content .action i:hover {
  color: #00c983; 
}

.clicked {
  background-color: #CAF1FF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 0 rgba(0,153,255,0.3);
}

.edit {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #00c983;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 0 rgba(0,153,255,0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 12px; 
}

.subtitle-label {
  color: #999; 
}

.input-sub {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.input-sub-line {
  display: table-row; 
  width: 100%;
}

.input-sub-label {
  display: table-cell; 
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999;
}

.input-sub {
  display: table-cell; 
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group {
  display: none; 
  padding: 22px 24px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" value=0>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">Education</div>
    <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="input-main"></div>
    <div class="action"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></div>
    <div class="action-edit">
      <div class="cancel"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
      <div class="check"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="caption">1-Attribute Card</div>

<div class="card" value=0>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title"><span class="title-main">Education</span><br><span class="subtitle"><span class="subtitle-label">Code </span><span class="title-sub">030</span></span></div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-main">
      <div class="input-sub-line">
        <div class="input-sub-label">Code</div> 
        <input class="input-sub" type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="action"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></div>
    <div class="action-edit">
      <div class="cancel cancel-tall"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
      <div class="check check-tall"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="caption">2-Attributes Card</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see... so the problem is not the shadow but the border. thank you! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I just noticed however, that my fix doesn't work for the second card. This is because there are more borders added to it in the inputs. If you want, I can look into this for a fix aswell.

Comment: Actually on my snippet the 2nd card doesn't grow that much, the height increase is the same as the 1st card. I don't know why it looks different here, but after I change as per your input it works great. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first box you can start by changing `border` to `outline` in the .edit class since that is adding 2px to the height.

This does not solve the second box where it has extra content inside the card. Might want to make the caption `position: absolute;`

Comment: Good answer. The 2nd card works just fine on my page, thanks :)